# Ubuntu messed up Windows Bootloader (MBR)

Tags: boot, multi-boot, windows-7, mbr

I recently tried installing Ubuntu and dualbooting it. I selected the "install alongside Windows 7" option and created a ~60GB partition, and it followed through well. When I wanted to return to Windows, though, GRUB GNU would select it but return to the menu shortly after, so I uninstalled Ubuntu (via "Try Ubuntu" from USB) with OS-Remover. Now, when I try to boot from HDD, it gives me "error: unknown filesystem" and is stuck in grub restore mode. I have tried the following:

-Used Boot Repair from Ubuntu (USB)

-Inserted an installation USB and tried bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot, says successful yet only made the USB unbootable and had to reformat and burn, still brings to grub rescue

-Tried burning eBCD (wouldn't boot)

-Doing "cd boot" from CMD via installation USB gives me an error saying the path doesn't exist

-Tried a multitude of other tutorials

Can someone help me completely remove GRUB and restore MBR? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A long shot... but could they be installed in different BIOS versions? Ubuntu in UEFI and Windows in Legacy? In such case you will have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Niklas sounds to be right on target

Comment: After more research, I decided that reinstalling Windows is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in a similar situation before and used this tutorial to resolve the issue: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/  If an encrypted install of Ubuntu was done, I don't think the filesystem can be found.

Comment: It says the filesystem for all the partitions is unknown (hd0 and hd1) and the guide is only for repairing Linux installations.